# Scrolling in Appium

Tags: appium

I am automating a Tablet application using Appium + Java. In a screen, I have 100+ fields (Textbox + Dropdown) to automate which has scroll view.

To automate those 100+ fields, I have listed down all the IDs(of those textbox and dropdown in that screen) along with the test Cases and Test Data in separate Excel sheets. My code runs in a loop, picks Test Case, its Data and relevant ID and executes. So, my code looks like:

```
loop : for(int j = 1; j <= fieldCount; j++)
{
    objElementRepositoryLibrary.setElementRepositoryDataLibrary(j);

    switch(ElementRepositoryLibrary.getElementType()) {

    case "AutoPopulated":
        System.out.println(ElementRepositoryLibrary.getElementValue() + " is Autopopulated");
        break;

    case "Dropdown": 
        ElementOperation.checkElementState(qdeDriver, ElementRepositoryLibrary.getLocator(), ElementRepositoryLibrary.getElementValue());

        if(ElementOperation.ElementAcceess.equals(false))
            System.out.println(ElementRepositoryLibrary.getElementValue() + " is disabled");
        else
            objElementOperation.dropdownSelectListner(qdeDriver, ElementRepositoryLibrary.getLocator(), ElementRepositoryLibrary.getElementValue(), field[0][j-1]);
        break;

    case "Button":
        ElementOperation.checkElementState(qdeDriver, ElementRepositoryLibrary.getLocator(), ElementRepositoryLibrary.getElementValue());

        if(ElementOperation.ElementAcceess.equals(false)) {
            System.out.println(ElementRepositoryLibrary.getElementValue() + " is disabled");
            break loop;
        }
        else if(field[0][j-1].equals(""))
            System.out.println("Checking for Null value");
        else if(field[0][j-1].equals("Yes") && ElementRepositoryLibrary.getFieldName().equals("QR Scanner"))
            objElementOperation.buttonClickListner(qdeDriver, ElementRepositoryLibrary.getLocator(), ElementRepositoryLibrary.getElementValue());
        else if(ElementRepositoryLibrary.getFieldName().contains("Capture Document"))
            objElementOperation.captureDocument(qdeDriver, ElementRepositoryLibrary.getLocator(), ElementRepositoryLibrary.getElementValue());
            break;

    default :
        objElementOperation.textboxSetListner(qdeDriver, ElementRepositoryLibrary.getElementType(), ElementRepositoryLibrary.getLocator(), 
                ElementRepositoryLibrary.getElementValue(), field[0][j-1]);
        break;
    }   
}
```

ISSUE: After filling few(say 7) fields, it is giving me NoSuchElementException because I have to scroll in the screen to move to the next fields(It goes like: screen contains 7 fields & you have to scroll to view the fields below and automator will nor recognize the element until it is viewed in the screen).

What I had tried is, I did catch for NoSuchElementException and performed Scroll operation. But it is not the proper way to do because if the element which has been searched is not present in actual, then also it will catch NoSuchElementException and perform scroll operation.

Suggest some good way to eliminate this issue. Let me know if any detail needed.

Comment: is it possible that 2 items (or more) in the dropdown list will have the same values?

Comment: @DavidEp, No, it can`t be. 
Was this question relevant?

Comment: Yes - i think that i can give you an answer

Answer (score 0):

As i understand from you the code works fine, so what i would do to make this test complete:

1. (As you already did) Press on the dropdown list and search for the item - in this case you did right to ignore NoSuchElementException.
2. Save the name of the last visible item (If you need any help with code snippets please let me know)
3. Perform scroll again and search for the item -> save the last item again.
4. After a few iterations, the last item will be left the same -> it means that we are at the end of the list, in this case you fail the test.

Comment: I guess, you misunderstood my question.
It is not the dropdown with has long list(what i referred to 100+ elements) of options. It is actually `Elements` which contain both **textboxes** and **dropdowns**. In short what I mean is, it is form having numerous fields.

Comment: But, your answer gave me a idea to work my way around.
Let me try. If it work, I`ll post the correct answer.